# Cannot run python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a stand-alone python file partitions.py that is in my home folder. When I type the command "python3 partition.py" the script runs.

However, when I type "python3 -m partition.py" it gives me an error
"/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named partition.py"

I do not know why this is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the file `partition.py` located in a directory that is in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: Because there isn't a *module* named `partition.py`; there is a *file* named `partition.py`. The corresponding *module* is named `partition`, which is what the `-m flag expects. Please see the linked duplicate for a full overview of `-m`.

Answer (score 4):

To run the module as script directly use:

```
python3 -m partition
```

(without the `.py` ending).

That will cause python to search `sys.path` for a module called `partition` and execute it. `partition.py` in this context would mean a module in a file `partition/py.py`.

Comment: In your case the home directory presented in sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

See the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), specifically that the module must be on the path, and the extension shouldn't be included.